# do we need process.exit(1) when we use promises in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

In our company we are having a discussion of sorts regarding whether we need exit a process in the event of an unhandled exception in node.js while using promises

Two schools of thoughts have been playing on my mind

- when we use promises in node.js we need to use process.exit(1)
- we don't need to use process.exit(1) when we use promises

By the way we are planning to use the blubird module for promises.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird

I want to know whether its necessary to exit the process in the event of an unhandled exception as while using promises we get "finally" statement to cleanup the resources

http://canop.org/blog/?p=516

Also what types of errors can we expect when it comes to node.js that promises might not be able to handle by itself, if there are any, which we might need to handle via

```
process.on("uncaughtException")
{
process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: In a line - no, you do not. Promises are throw safe. That's like the point of promises. Your code gains desirable properties of synchronous code like returning and throwing.

Comment: Note you _should_ use typed catches. Especially check out OperationalError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.finally` is not very good for resource management:

- It can be forgotten and only a careful audit can find forgotten cleanups
- It can subtly leak resources in more complicated scenarios

That's why 2.0 introduced [`using`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#resource-management), it's virtually impossible to forget to use it because a promise for resource is actually a disposer which can only be used with `using`.

So if you acquire your resources with `using`, there is no need to restart from the errors that happen within.

Note that this doesn't cover bugs in libraries, if you are using a library that leaks resources then you need to restart your process. For example there is nothing you can do about https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7697 (except fork node and use promises in core so this kind of thing is impossible :D).

Comment: is there like a global error callback in promises that i can use in case i want to log such errors like the one u mentioned

Comment: @Nav I didn't mention an error but a bug in a library that uses callbacks

Comment: aah ...k...what about using it for mongodb transactions.. are promises stable for that ??? any bugs that u might have encountered before like the one mentioned in this thread http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb

Comment: @Nav it's not a question of what you can do, if there is a bug in the library you are using the only thing you can do is to use another library, it has nothing to do whether *you* are using promises or not.

Comment: @Nav The blog post talks about something different - errors and leaks that are *your* fault, those are completely eliminated by using `using`

Comment: @Nav you need to exit the process if some library is leaking resources because the bug is in the library, not your code

Comment: thank you for the quick answer.. I have however one confusion, how do we find if there is an uncaught exception outside of promisified code... a bug for example... do we handle those externally via prcoess.on("uncaughtexception") when we dont have direct access to the buggy module???

Comment: @Nav Well in the node core case there is nothing you could do to detect the leak - so it would require you to periodically restart your process or track the amount of handles the process is reserving but both have downsides

Comment: sorry didn't get the part regarding periodic restart and amount of handlers... can u please explain with an example perhaps

Comment: @Nav Periodic restarting means that for example, every 2 hours, you shut down node process and then start it. That way any leaked resources will be freed.

Comment: it has nothing to do with uncaughtexception then, if i get u correctly..am i right in thinking that for a leak an uncaughtexception might not at all be raised... what do u think ???

Comment: @Nav yes there is no exception to be caught

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, no.

Long answer:

When you call `process.exit()` you cause processing to stop. The exit event is fired, which is the last opportunity for any code to run, and the event loop is stopped. Shortly thereafter Node.js actually stops completely and returns the specified exit code. So process.exit() stops Node.js from doing anything tangible after that point and the application stops.

**The problem**

The problem is that `process.exit()` can be called by any part of the application at any time. There is nothing preventing a parser from calling it:

```
exports.parse = function(text) {

    if (canParse(text)) {
        return doTheParse(text);
    } else {
        console.error("Can't parse the text.");
        process.exit(1);
    }

};
```

So if the text can be parsed then it is, but otherwise an error is output to the console and process.exit(1) is called. That’s an awful lot of responsibility for a lowly parser.

Since any module can call `process.exit()`, that means any function call gone awry could decide to shut down the application. That’s not a good state to be in. There should be one area of an application that decides when and if to call `process.exit()` and what the exit code should be (that’s usually the application controller). Utilities and such should never use `process.exit()`, it’s way out of their realm of responsibility.

Anytime you’re thinking about using process.exit(), consider throw an error instead:

Throwing an error has a similar effect as calling process.exit() in that code execution in this function stops immediately. However, calling functions have the opportunity to catch the error and respond to it in a graceful manner. If there is no intervention up the call stack, then the `uncaughtException` event is fired on process. If there are no event handlers, then Node.js will fire the exit event and exit with a non-zero exit code just like when process.exit() is called; if there are event handlers, then it is up to you to manually call process.exit() to specify the exit code to use.

The key is that throwing an error gives the application an opportunity to catch the error and recover from it, which is almost always the desired case when dealing with module code.

source: [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/02/04/maintainable-node-js-javascript-avoid-process-exit/)

Comment: Just because arbitrary code can call process.exit doesn't mean arbitrary code does. by that same logic that code can format your computer or open a backdoor. **edit** sorry I misread, we're in fact arguing the same point.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that unlike popular belief. A server restart on every error isn't a viable error handling strategy in Node, what it is is the fast path to a DOS vulnerability.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what about the point Esailiza made regarding a buggy module???

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Is refused connection to database significant enough error to stop server? Can you suggest better approach to handle this error or recover from it?

Comment: No, it is not - see Esailija's answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Okey, please confirm, that I understand things correctly. Suppose I have some express app, which uses database. In case if database connection fails on startup (or at any other point) I should keep application running and reply with error to all incoming requests instead of stopping application? Then I need to understand what's went wrong and do some actions to recover application manually, e.g. fix database and restart application?

Comment: @devoto13 if the DB failed to connect then you can attempt to retry to connect to it - personally I almost always have a cache in front of the DB I can keep serving clients from - the thing is: restarting the server will unlikely solve a problem like failing to connect to the DB anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you, I think you answer mean I am right and it's better to keep application in partially broken state (or try to recover automatically) instead of restarting it if "restarting the server will unlikely solve a problem".